# Obj-C PCX data to Image (xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way in obj-c (xcode iphone) to show an image that comes from a PCX data?
I have a NSData object with all the binary data of the PCX image.

Answer (score 0):

*I have a NSData object with all the binary data of the PCX image.*

`UIImage` Class reference: There is an instance method initWithData: `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data`

```
UIImage * pcxImage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pcxData] autorelease];
// where pcxData is NSData object of binary data of the image
```

Then use `UIImageView` to add it as subView to your view or do whatever

```
UIImageView * myImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pcxImage] autorelease];
[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f,50.0f,100.0f,100.0f)];
[self.view addSubView:myImageView];
```

Comment: I tried using this solution but when debugging the pcxImage var is 0x0. So i'm not sure what the problem is. My NSData contains the binary info so that part its ok. My guess is that UIImage does not support PCX? i'm not sure but i wasn't able to find anything over the internet.